A power series involving binomial and poisson
During my study, I have come across the following power series involving both binomial and poisson components:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B}{B + 2n} \Biggl(\binom{B + 2n}{n} p^{n} (1-p)^{B+n}\Biggr) e^{-\lambda} 
\frac{\lambda^{B + 2n}}{(B + 2n)!} $$
Could anyone suggest me how to calculate this infinite summation or a way to approximate it? Thank you very much!

Use approach zero website, link https://approach0.xyz/search/

If $a_n$ is the summand
$$\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\lambda ^2 (1-p) p}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ So, in principle, the convergence could be quite fast.
There is a closed form of the summation in terms of hypergeometric function but this not help very much since it hides again an infinite summation.
It would be
$$\frac{e^{-\lambda }\, \lambda ^b\, (1-p)^b}{\Gamma(b+1)}\,\,\, _1F_2\left(\frac{b}{2};\frac{b}{2}+1,b+1;\lambda ^2 (1-p) p\right)$$
But, if $b$ is an even iteger, this reduces to Bessel functions
$$F(b)=\, _1F_2\left(\frac{b}{2};\frac{b}{2}+1,b+1;x^2\right)$$
$$F(2)=\frac{2 I_1(2 x)}{x^3}-\frac{2}{x^2}$$
$$F(4)=\frac{48 I_3(2 x)}{x^5}-\frac{48 I_2(2 x)}{x^6}+\frac{24}{x^4}$$
$$F(6)=-\frac{12960 I_4(2 x)}{x^8}+\frac{2160 \left(x^2+2\right) I_3(2 x)}{x^9}-\frac{720}{x^6}$$
If $b$ is a odd integer, the formulae become more complex (they include also Struve functions).
